# Jquery with PHP search function

Tags: php, jquery

I'm workings hours to find a solution to fix a problem

I'm using 2 pages: on the first page **additem.php** I want to add some items to right section.

I've a database where i've ordered all items, If i search for 'boots' the page won't refresh and I will get all items related to 'boots', but the problem is I do not get anything. For example Im on the page **additem.php?i=Hobbo&g=CATEGORY** I want to add some items to 'Hobbo' Which is in category 'CATEGORY' and I search for 'boots' I want to select everything that sounds like 'boots'

Search form:

```
  <?php
    if (isset($_GET['i']) && isset($_GET['g']))
    {
    $i = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_GET['i']));
    $g = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_GET['g']));
    $gi    = $db->query("SELECT * FROM log_items INNER JOIN log_mobs ON log_items.game = log_mobs.game WHERE log_items.game = '" .$g. "' AND log_mobs.game = '" .$g. "' AND log_mobs.name = '" .$i. "'") or die($db->error);
    $gk     = $db->query("SELECT * FROM log_items WHERE game = '" .$g. "'") or die($db->error);
    if($gi->num_rows==0){
    echo '<p>This mob is not created yet on this game!</p>';
    } else {        
    ?>  <p>
    Item: <input type="text" class="edit" name="name" method="post" id="name"><br><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="game" id="game" value="<?php echo $g ?>"/>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="name-submit" value="Grab item">
    <div id="name-data"></div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/global.js"></script>
        </p>
    <?php
    }

}
?>
```

This is my Jquery:

```
$('input#name-submit').on('click', function() {
    var name = $('input#name').val();
    if ($.trim(name) != '') {
        $.post('name.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
            $('div#name-data').text(data);
        });
    }
});
```

This is the page where I actually need results from but I don't get anything

```
<?php
require '../config.php';
require_once '../core/init.php';
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['game'])) {
    $naame = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name']));
    $gaame = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['game']));
    $query_90 = "SELECT * FROM log_items 
            INNER JOIN log_mobs ON log_mobs.game  = log_items.game 
            WHERE log_items.name like '%$naame%' 
            AND log_items.game = '" .$gaame. "'";
    $result_90 = $db->query($query_90) or die ($db->error());

    $n_90 = $result_90->num_rows;
    if($n_90 == 0) {
        echo 'no results';
    } else {
        while ($row_90 = $result_90->fetch_object()) {
            echo htmlspecialchars($row_90->name);
            echo 'ok';
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Did you check if your additems script is running properly at all? Did you manually check the DB if your hobbo category is actually there?

Comment: I think we should remind stackoverflow users that this site is not a bug fixing forum. You should always ask for global answers that could also benefit another person.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your issue:

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['game'])) {
```

All you are posting is name not game.

```
 $.post('name.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
```